# Converting a 2d array of ints to char and string in Java

Tags: java, arrays, string, char, int

How can I convert the ints in a 2d array into chars, and strings? (seperately)

If I copy ints to a char array i just get the ASCII code.

For example:

```
public int a[5][5] 

//some code

public String b[5][5] = public int a[5][5]
```

Thanks

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Please give sample input and required output data.

Comment: You can have only one char in cell. How do you want to make strings from it? Which direction?

Comment: just instead of having an int in a cell, replace it with a char(or string). E.G. [0][0] = 5 as an int converted to [0][0] = 5 as a char. Justing replacing the int values with the char or string equivalent. I am hoping to replicate the int array as a char array and a string array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is not very well-phrased at all.  I THINK what you're asking is how to convert a two-level array of type `int[][]` to one of type `String[][]`.

Quite frankly, the easiest approach would simply leave your array as-is... and convert `int` values to `String`'s when you use them:

```
Integer.toString(a[5][5]);
```

Alternatively, you could start with a `String[][]` array in the first place, and simply convert your `int` values to `String` when adding them:

```
a[5][5] = new String(myInt);
```

If you really do need to convert an array of type `int[][]` to one of type `String[][]`, you would have to do so manually with a two-layer `for()` loop:

```
String[][] converted = new String[a.length][];
for(int index = 0; index < a.length; index++) {
    converted[index] = new String[a[index].length];
    for(int subIndex = 0; subIndex < a[index].length; subIndex++){
        converted[index][subIndex] = Integer.toString(a[index][subIndex]);
    }
}
```

All three of these approaches would work equally well for conversion to type `char` rather than `String`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code must basically go through your array and transform each int value into a String. You can do this with the [`String.toString(int)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toString%28int%29) method.

You can try that :

```
String[][] stringArray = new String[a.length][];
for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
    stringArray[i] = new String[a[i].lenght];
    for(int j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++){
        stringArray[i][j] = Integer.toString(a[i][j]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the int number as a string then you can use the `Integer.toString()` function.

```
b[1][1] = Integer.toString(a[1][1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String [][]b = new String[a.length][];
for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
  int [] row = a[i];
  b[i] = new String[row.length];
  for(int j=0; j<row.length; j++) {
    b[i][j] = Integer.toString(row[j]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To convert a 2D array into String you can use `Arrays.deepToString(stringArr)`.